# Delete all files from Downloads if file name contains specific string "-Open"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro enabled workbook that is saved in the asset folder of my website built through adobe experience manager that links back to a shared drive. It opens, links to the document, and closes itself. I need the macro to then go back and delete my 'opener file', which is the macro enabled workbook so I don't have the end user have multiple opener files in their downloads.

It will always be in Downloads folder & various opener files all have -Open in their name. Is there a specific code I can use to delete these files only? They all have different names such as 'Report 1-Open' or 'Report 2-Open'

Comment: does case matter and will it always be at the end with letters "-Open" ?

Comment: I am naming the files, so I will always name them with "-Open" at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `InStr` function that checks if a string contains other string:

```
IF INSTR(1, FILENAME, "Open") then DeleteFile.
```

Where `FILENAME` would be a variable that holds current file name.